# Create column that groups and transform data from the day before

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a new column that will group by ColA, and the result will be the summation of values in ColC of the **day before** -- example below:

Original DF

```
 ColA     ColB         ColC
  A     10/20/2021      2
  A     10/20/2021      8
  A     10/21/2021      1
  A     10/21/2021      5
  A     10/22/2021      3
  A     10/22/2021      4
  B     10/20/2021      9
  B     10/20/2021      1
  B     10/21/2021      6
  B     10/21/2021      4 
  B     10/22/2021      2
  B     10/22/2021      7 
  C     10/20/2021      6
  C     10/20/2021      3
  C     10/21/2021      8
  C     10/21/2021      8
  C     10/22/2021      2
  C     10/22/2021      6
```

Desired DF where new column is ColD

```
 ColA     ColB         ColC      ColD
  A     10/20/2021      2         NA
  A     10/20/2021      8         NA
  A     10/21/2021      1         10
  A     10/21/2021      5         10
  A     10/22/2021      3          6
  A     10/22/2021      4          6
  B     10/20/2021      9         NA
  B     10/20/2021      1         NA
  B     10/21/2021      6         10
  B     10/21/2021      4         10
  B     10/22/2021      2         10
  B     10/22/2021      7         10
  C     10/20/2021      6         NA
  C     10/20/2021      3         NA
  C     10/21/2021      8         9
  C     10/21/2021      8         9
  C     10/22/2021      2         16
  C     10/22/2021      6         16
```

Any suggestions is appreciated!

Comment: "Day before" is this exactly one day earlier or the previous date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert your date to a `datetime`. Then groupby 'ColA' and 'ColB' shifted by exactly one day. This way when you merge the result of the `groupby` back it aligns on one day earlier.

```
import pandas as pd

df['ColB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ColB'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

s = (df.groupby(['ColA', df['ColB']+pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=1)])
       ['ColC'].sum().rename('ColD'))

df = df.merge(s, on=['ColA', 'ColB'], how='left')
```

---

```
print(df)

   ColA       ColB  ColC  ColD
0     A 2021-10-20     2   NaN
1     A 2021-10-20     8   NaN
2     A 2021-10-21     1  10.0
3     A 2021-10-21     5  10.0
4     A 2021-10-22     3   6.0
5     A 2021-10-22     4   6.0
6     B 2021-10-20     9   NaN
7     B 2021-10-20     1   NaN
8     B 2021-10-21     6  10.0
9     B 2021-10-21     4  10.0
10    B 2021-10-22     2  10.0
11    B 2021-10-22     7  10.0
12    C 2021-10-20     6   NaN
13    C 2021-10-20     3   NaN
14    C 2021-10-21     8   9.0
15    C 2021-10-21     8   9.0
16    C 2021-10-22     2  16.0
17    C 2021-10-22     6  16.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing a `groupby` then we `shift` it within the colA and `merge` back

```
out = df.merge(df.groupby(['ColA','ColB'])['ColC'].sum().groupby(level=0).shift().reset_index(name='ColD'))
Out[71]: 
   ColA        ColB  ColC  ColD
0     A  10/20/2021     2   NaN
1     A  10/20/2021     8   NaN
2     A  10/21/2021     1  10.0
3     A  10/21/2021     5  10.0
4     A  10/22/2021     3   6.0
5     A  10/22/2021     4   6.0
6     B  10/20/2021     9   NaN
7     B  10/20/2021     1   NaN
8     B  10/21/2021     6  10.0
9     B  10/21/2021     4  10.0
10    B  10/22/2021     2  10.0
11    B  10/22/2021     7  10.0
12    C  10/20/2021     6   NaN
13    C  10/20/2021     3   NaN
14    C  10/21/2021     8   9.0
15    C  10/21/2021     8   9.0
16    C  10/22/2021     2  16.0
17    C  10/22/2021     6  16.0
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this. Do you expect this will work if the dataframe has other columns that are not related to this effort?

Comment: @dmd7 will work